# Error while uploading images through SOAP in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am having trouble in uploading the image in magento ce 1.7 through my soap api. I am uploading the images but it is creating a temp path inside var/api/sessionid/imgname. Sometimes in that path i am getting the image does not exists error.

Here is the detailed description of what i am doing.

My function for image uploading -

```
catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(lstr_sessionId, lstr_productId, oProductImage, StoreId.ToString(), "");
```

My error -

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: File `C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\var\api\dece42536f86f2996f38d2bd9ab4a23f\SHIMANO ULTEGRA BR/66X BK BAK.jpg` does not exists

Please suggest any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved ,I found out that the webservice dont accept file names with special Characters
Passing image name without special characters solved my issue